Could Neem Oil for aphids harm things that eat them?
I have some mum plants that I managed to keep alive from last year. However, they have a stubborn aphid infestation. I just moved them outside (they had been inside), partially in the hope that natural predators would help the situation.
I also did another application of Neem Oil. However, I'm questioning whether that was a good idea. What happens if a predator ate an aphid that ate Neem Oil? Would they be harmed by that?

Sure, Neem Oil will kill most insects on the plant including natural predators that are are there when you spray.  However if you just moved them outside it is unlikely that the local predator insects had time to find the new food.
The half life of need oil is only a few days so you should be fine to repeat the spray in four or five days.  Just look for predators first before spraying.

What if a predator ate an aphid that ate Neem oil?

@EJoshuaS-StandwithUkraine The reference says "It is important to remember that insects must eat the treated plant to be killed. Therefore, bees and other pollinators are not likely to be harmed."  Predators might be harmed but there is no research.
